# Pause in a cron script due to restrictions on a system

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sleep

I have a cron scripts that logs into another server, getts the information to update my tables in my db, and when finished it closes the connection and sends me an email.

The problem I am now getting is that they have deployed a restriction that says I can only update 20 rows per 60 seconds.

I have looked at the sleep() function, and someone is suggestion create batches, and so on. What's the best way to handle this, and getting a good solution. I need the script to continue until all rows in that table are updated.

Comment: Note that if there are more than 20 rows added per minute, your download will never catch up with the data.  If they are imposing the restriction, all you have to do is try working as fast as you can and they'll stop you exceeding their limit.  If they are requesting you to impose the limit on yourself, then you have to mess around with something like `sleep(3)` after each row.

Comment: Hmm, I tried many different methods now, but it seems that it "finsish" after 20 rows, and I now doesnt really know if the problem is that is the sleeping function I added or that it logs out from the system in meantime when the sleep() is running. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is indeed how you generally do this. In PHP, `sleep` can only sleep for full seconds, so use `usleep` or `time_nanosleep` if you do the second method.

If you want to make the assumption that all your queries execute instantly, and you're just running a batch, then it's very easy to limit to 20 rows per 60 seconds: sleep 3 second after each row. If your queries aren't instant, you wind up inserting fewer rows per second.

If you want, you can time the insert, and sleep for 3-elapsed seconds, this will guarantee 20 rows per 60 seconds, as long as each row individually is less than 3 seconds to insert. If they run longer, you'll fall below 20 per 60 seconds. I suggest this isn't really worth it—it'll have the bad side effect of making your inserter work harder when the database is already overloaded.

If you're not in autocommit mode, you'll want to commit fairly frequently—its generally a bad idea to hold uncommitted changes for longer than necessary.

Finally, if you must maintain 20 rows/60 seconds averaged over a longer time period (and your incoming data is bursty), you get to move towards a token-bucket filter: Every 3 seconds (60÷20 seconds), you add a "token" to the "bucket". The bucket holds up to 20 tokens. Each time you insert a row, you remove a token from the bucket—if the bucket is empty, you wait until it isn't.